# Fill rate of all the columns in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I want to calculate the fill rate % of all the columns present in my particular database.
For the null-fraction we have this query:

```sql
SELECT tablename,
       attname,
       null_frac
FROM pg_stats
WHERE schemaname = 'public';
```

Likewise, how can we calculate the fill rate (%) of all columns?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean with "fill rate"? Filled based on what maximum?

Comment: Hello. for example: A column has 10 records  but only 5 records contains values and other 5 records contains null values/ blank. So, fill rate is 50%.

Comment: in the same way if the 6 records contains values while 4 records contains null values/blank then fill rate is 60%

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the official Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/view-pg-stats.html#:%7E:text=null_frac,that%20are%20null) the null_frac is based on the count of NULL values the rest represents the values in the column.
So `1 - null_frac` will give you the fill-rate e.g.

```sql
SELECT attname AS col,
       (1 - null_frac) * 100 AS fill_rate,
       null_frac * 100 AS null_rate,
       fill_rate + null_rate AS total    -- 100%
FROM pg_stats
WHERE schemaname = 'schema_name'
  AND tablename = 'table_name'
;
```

Note this also works in AWS Redshift.